# Converting datetime format maintaining the datetime data type in python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, strptime, strftime

I need datetime object in the format mm/dd/yyyy. I tried using `strptime`:

```
datetime.strptime("05-08-2022","%d-%m-%Y")
>>datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 5, 0, 0)
```

That changes the format to YYYY/MM/DD.
I know we can change the format using `strftime` to convert datetime to any format but that results into a string object. **I would like retain it as datetime object along with format mm/dd/yyyy.**

Another thing, I have tried is to set the locale to french datetime format (mm/dd/yyyy [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-7/index.html)):

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8'))
datetime.strptime("05-08-2022","%d-%m-%Y")
>>datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 5, 0, 0)
```

However, that did not work either. Are there any other way to convert 'strings or dates' to datetime objects maintaining the format mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: The `datetime` object has no format. It just has `year`, `month` etc attributes. What you see when you print it is just how the developers decided to represent it as a string, it will always be in the same order (format) for all `datetime` objects. What do you need this for?

Comment: I understand your problem, but I don't understand why you want to change the reprentation of a datetime object (the __repr__ method). I mean why can't you just use strftime to have a string and the representation you want. if you really want to do so, create a new class that is a simple copy of a datetime.datetime object but with your own __repr__ method

Comment: @FilipMüller this is the client's requirement unfortunately!

Comment: What does he want it for?

Comment: @FilipMüller I really do not know. But he is stubborn about it. I willing to edit the built-in package if need be!

Comment: Best would be to tell him it doesn't make any sense, this just makes a difference during printing and automatic string conversion. But if it needs to be done, override the `datetime.__repr__` method.

Comment: What does your client need to do with `datetime` objects directly exactly that this is a requirement? Are they programmers themselves? Can't imagine this is not something that a strftime wouldn't fix. But might be missing something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you'll need to create a new class and specify your own `__repr__` method.

```
import datetime 

class DateTime:
    def __init__(self, datetime_instance):
        self.datetime = datetime_instance

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"datetime.datetime({self.datetime.month}, {self.datetime.day}, {self.datetime.year})"
    
a = datetime.datetime(year=2000, month=12, day=15)
b = DateTime(a)
```

Output for `a` :

```
a
>>datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 15, 0, 0)
```

Output for `b` :

```
b
>>datetime.datetime(12, 15, 2000)
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply overriding the method of `datetime` be easier? I know it feels dirty, but this whole problem is messy as hell anyways.

Comment: Override? That would mean monkey patching it. Which is evil :P

Comment: @ThePjot yes, generally. But here it's just a `__repr__` method and it's really the only way to solve what the client wants word for word. This solution now has you accessing the `datetime` like `my_date.datetime` every time, which isn't pretty either. Plus the `__repr__` is supposed to give developers information about what the object is. Imagine trying to debug this later while the object swears it is a `datetime` in it's `repr` even though it's not and it's some strange `DateTime` somebody implemented for whatever reason:D.